# Defined integral with min function.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to resolve an integral that I didn't see before and I can't find any examples online.
So my integral is: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \min(1, \tan (x)) dx $$
I have no idea what $\min(1, \tan x)$ means. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\min\{1,\tan(x)\}$ is just the smaller of the two; in other words,
$$
\min\{1,\tan(x)\}=\begin{cases} \tan(x) & \text{if }\tan(x)<1\\1 & \text{else}\end{cases}.
$$
So, just like with any piecewise-defined function, to compute the integral of this function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, you need to break the region up in to parts: the parts where $\tan(x)<1$, and the parts where $\tan(x)\geq 1$.

Comment: Oh , great! Thank you! I will check as answer in 8 min.Thank you again.

Comment: @user137209 My pleasure!